# Ссылка на динамической странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть страница.

```
usluga.php
```

На основе передаваемого параметра формируется страница с описание и тд,затем этот параметр превращается в ЧПУ,в итоге все это дело выглядит примерно так

```
usluga/nameusl
```

И теперь на этой страницы не работают ссылки и подключения файлов (css/js) приходиться их полностью прописывать

```
<link href="www.sitename.com/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

можно ли как то делать так,чтобы ссылки вида

```
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

работали

Если в сделать вместо

```
usluga/nameusl
usluga-nameusl
```

Все как надо работает

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^usluga/([^/]+)/?$ usluga.php?link=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Тут явно не хватает htacess.

Comment: @labris, Вот добавил

Comment: Я бы тут использовал для адресов переменную $_SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Страница `usluga/nameusl` оказывается на уровень дальше от хоста, чем страница `usluga`.

А значит, либо надо ставить две точки и слеш перед адресом CSS (но тогда не будет корректно работать "простая" страница `usluga`, либо

Прописать для адреса CSS файла следующее:

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/css/style.css"; ?>
```

Тогда адрес CSS файла не будет зависеть от места, из которого его вызывают.